# Facebook auth via FirebaseUI

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, firebaseui

I have been making Facebook authentication via FirebaseUI. I've done everything that is said here, but Facebook authentication does not work. When I press the auth button something is loading and after that I appear in the signinactivity again. No mistakes in the log, no app crashes. Here is what the logcat says after the sign in attempt

```
11-03 22:17:52.784 10993-10993/com.gamebubbles.run I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.gamebubbles.run time:146927353
11-03 22:17:53.398 10993-10993/com.gamebubbles.run I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.facebook.katana time:146927967
11-03 22:17:53.767 10993-10993/com.gamebubbles.run I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@e085d33 time:146928336
11-03 22:17:54.154 10993-10993/com.gamebubbles.run D/AutoManageHelper: onStart true {1=com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqm$zza@5aa32d}
11-03 22:17:54.313 10993-10993/com.gamebubbles.run I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@bac15f3 time:146928883
```

Maybe someone faced this problem and can help me?

---

Interesting fact is that in developer.facebook.com in the login statistics there is one log in noticed (its me) so the auth must be working.

---

Comment: I had the same problem with `FirebaseUI`. Turned out that i forgot to add my app to `developer.facebook.com`

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez i added my app to developer.facebook.com You had just the same problem? Maybe i ve done something incorrectly there if you had the same problem.

Comment: It was because i was using an old `KeyHash` and forgot to update in my fb app.

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez hm, i use release hashkey, it can not change. Or it can change?

Comment: try using debug hashkey. I used debug.

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez but will it work when i ll release my app?

Comment: No you have to change it back when you release you app.

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez i think in my case the problem is not with the keyhash, as i added the key, but it is not working